# help regarding dynamic redirect rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, redirect

I need ur help for given subject.
I am playing with  htaccess rules first time in life.

here is the scene -

i want to redirect the urls -

```
 http://www.abc.com/var1
 http://www.abc.com/var2
```

to follwing urls -

```
 http://www.abc.com/index.php?u=var1
 http://www.abc.com/index.php?u=var2
```

In this case the values var1 & var2  can be anything (i.e. string which will contain only alphanumeric characters.)

One more thing -

I want to skip this rule if the url is -

http://www.abc.com/SKIPME

Please help me to write this rule!

Regards,
Shahu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off defining a URI schema that tells you when something WILL be rewritten. For example...

```
 http://www.abc.com/site/var1
 http://www.abc.com/site/var2
```

That way, you can ensure you only ever apply the rule if the psuedo "site/" directory is browsed and not affect any other URI. This is the rewrite rule based on the above schema.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Any other address, other than "/site/.../" would be unaffected by this rule, which means you don't need to worry about setting some addresses to be avoided. This keeps things as simple as possible.

You don't have to use "site" - you can use whatever name fits your purpose.