# Website redirect folder to php script

Tags: php, redirect, web, directory

I am programming an website and I want to redirect specific URL like

```
    www.example.org/p/home
    www.example.org/p/user/th3falc0n
```

to my script

```
    www.example.org/index.php?page=home
    www.example.org/index.php?page=user/th3falc0n
```

without the user recognizing that the server is redirecting this page to the script.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need .htaccess rewrite to do that - http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Comment: The other option, if mod_rewrite is not available:
Using native PHP you can strip the URL and redirect using a Switch Case setup

Comment: Wouldn't that show the user though? I don't know, I've never tried it, sounds interesting though.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in IIS to? (I am developing the site with WebMatrix, on the server it works fine, but on my client IIS server .htaccess is ignored!?)

Comment: If you can't use .htaccess, maybe you want to try what Paul is suggesting above - I have not tried this though. Seems weird though that you wouldn't be able to use simple .htaccess, I would verify with your host.

Answer (score 1):

Using .htaccess is usually the best way to approach this - it's a file which tells Apache (or your web server software) where the request should go.

Here is a previous question on this subject:
[help regarding dynamic redirect rule in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688689/help-regarding-dynamic-redirect-rule-in-htaccess)

Answer quoted here:

> http://www.abc.com/site/var1  http://www.abc.com/site/var2 That way,
>   you can ensure you only ever apply the rule if the psuedo "site/"
>   directory is browsed and not affect any other URI. This is the rewrite
>   rule based on the above schema.
>
> RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^site/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?u=$1
>   [L,NC,QSA] Any other address, other than "/site/.../" would be
>   unaffected by this rule, which means you don't need to worry about
>   setting some addresses to be avoided. This keeps things as simple as
>   possible.
>
> You don't have to use "site" - you can use whatever name fits your
>   purpose.